# How to show data in Table Format in Android

Tags: android

I have designed an android app using Eclipse.Now as per my requirement i want to add table and show the result of submit button into tabular format.
Here is my code.

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome !"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vikas Technologies "
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Check PNR"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Train Enquiry"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="Enter PNR"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:color="#ffffff" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

           //Here i want to add Table


        <Space
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="5" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="166dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="6" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="0" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So How to add table in android.I am very novice in this field.

Here is the snapshot..

[image]

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA added the snap shot

Comment: AFter click on submit button need to display data below that button in tabular form?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Yes sir...Exactly same...

Comment: For that you need to tell that how many rows and columns you want to display

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Two rows and three columns sir

Comment: For that you need to make custom xml file and after  that inflate that file to your listview and display data in it.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA What is i want to show one row and three columns